# Can't get out of a loop

Tags: c, random, sdl-2

I am trying to create a random path by coloring cases of the SDL window, but it seems like my function can't get out of the loop, thus it gives me dancing shapes. Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define N 0
#define S 2
#define W 3
#define E 1

void drawRectangle(int n, SDL_Renderer* renderer, int i, int j){
    SDL_Rect rectangle;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    rectangle.x = j*(WIDTH/n);
    rectangle.y = i*(WIDTH/n);
    rectangle.w = WIDTH/n;
    rectangle.h = WIDTH/n;
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rectangle);
}

void create_path(int n,SDL_Renderer* renderer){
    int i,j,k;
    drawRectangle(n,renderer,0,1);
    drawRectangle(n,renderer,1,1);
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            k=rand()%4;
            if(k==N){
                drawRectangle(n,renderer, i-1, j);
            }
            else if(k==E){
                drawRectangle(n,renderer,i,j+1);
            }
            else if(k==S){
                drawRectangle(n,renderer,i+1,j);
            }
            else if(k==W){
                drawRectangle(n,renderer,i,j-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without following exactly what you do I see the loop `for(j=0;j<n;j++)` so you could be going out of range with `drawRectangle(n,renderer,i,j+1);` and `drawRectangle(n,renderer,i,j-1);` and perhaps same issue with `i` too. But I don't understand why you "can't get out of a loop" unless the calling functions are to blame.

Comment: What happens when you step through with a debugger?

Comment: I think the problem is with the k=rand()%4, because when I tried coloring few cases without the rand() it worked and stoped recoloring ! so I don't know why it doesn't stop when I use rand()

Comment: I repeat my earlier comment: what do you think will happen with `drawRectangle(n,renderer,i,j-1);` on the first iteration of `for(j=0;j<n;j++)`?

Comment: Oh yes I forgot ! for(j=1;j<n;j++)